# Android what widget is this

Tags: android, android-widget

Check the integer spinner in [image]the picture. Can someone tell me what widget it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a `NumberPicker`.

Note that you can use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to examine the UI of a running application and learn what widgets are used.